# Why I can't make instance outside of method

Tags: c#, syntax, instance

```c#
using System;

namespace FileApp
{

    public class status
    {
        public int speed;
    }

    public class Player
    {
        private status ddd = new status();
        ddd.speed = 3;


        static void Main()
        {
            status dd = new status();
            dd.speed = 3;
        }
    }

}
```

Why I can't use ddd.speed? Why I can't set ddd.speed to 3? Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because logical statements like that belong in a method, not in the class definition.  The class definition can define class members (fields, properties, methods), but not perform imperative logic.

In your `Main` method you already show how to do this:

```
status dd = new status();
dd.speed = 3;
```

---

Now, if you specifically want to access `ddd` in your `Main` method, take note of the fact that `Main` is `static` and therefore not associated with any given isntance of `Player`.  So you'd need an instance:

```
Player player = new Player();
```

And since `ddd` is `private`, you'd want something to allow you to access that field.  A *property* is useful for that sort of thing.  For example, define it as:

```
private status ddd = new status();
public status DDD { get { return ddd; } }
```

Which you could also shorten to simply:

```
public status DDD { get; private set; } = new status();
```

Then you can access it on your instance:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.DDD.speed = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have statements (other than member declaration and initialization) floating around directly under a class - you need to put them in a method or a constructor.